# Bootstrap's JS + CSS Modules - how can I get class names in JS to be the namespaced class names?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-5, vite, css-modules

I am attempting to use CSS modules with Bootstrap (in a React Vite app), the CSS part of that works beautifully and exactly as expected;

- just renaming `bootstrap.css` to `bootstrap.module.css`
- `import style from 'bootstrap.module.css'`
- `<div className={style.dropdown}...>` --> `<div class='_dropdown_0fd9s87"...>`

That works amazingly.

The problem then becomes the associated Bootstrap JS; it bundles perfectly fine, but the `dropdown` CSS class name is *hard-coded*. So my namespaced class name isn't picked-up (since `_dropdown_0fd9s87` !== `dropdown`).

Am I missing something that would take care of this? I've searched all over the place and can't even find others talking about this.

My use case is bundling an entire React app and `export`ing a function that does the `ReactDOM.createRoot().render()` then `import`ing that function into a page with a ton of legacy code, including old versions of Bootstrap, so I am using CSS modules to segregate my app's stylings from the rest of the page. It works wonderfully, just not when it comes to Bootstrap's JS.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].